# SSH session pauses mid datastream; resumes with a keypress

Tags: linux, ssh, signals

I've had this problem occur at random, intermittently, across boxes at multiple companies, multiple distros, and multiple kernel revs.  I think that I'm just cursed.

What happens is that I'll have a new box loaded, and I'll be doing something inside ssh, like a yum update or an apt-get.  Everything will be progressing fine and then the session just stops.  The ssh doesn't disconnect, it's almost as if someone sent a scroll lock keypress to the session.

If I hit enter, or space, or just about any keystroke in the ssh session, the session wakes back up and its as if nothing went wrong.

I once upon a time tracked down an issue like this and found that the interactive processes were entering SLEEP status.  I can't confirm that this is the same behavior in this case, but I will amend the question if I can pinpoint that specific cause.

Regardless, I was never able to figure out why the processes were randomly going into sleep.

Has anyone had this or a similar issue and have any insight into what might be causing it?

Comment: Sleep status just means there's nothing to run, not that it's Stopped. It may be interesting to attach to the process with strace when that happens and observe where it's sleeping and what happens when you press a key.

Comment: The remote endpoint is a bunch of different places, but what about the local endpoint? Is it always on the same network? If so, I put $10 on broken/misconfigured firewall on your network (or, I guess, your ISP's). Diagnose by running packet capture on both ends.

Comment: I cannot substantiate this claim so I won't post it as an answer, however we upgraded the boxes away from CentOS 6's -220 kernel release, and the problem went away for all boxes.

Comment: Did you manage to to solve this problem? I'm experiencing the same issue but only from one specific host. Works fine when I SSH from a different host.

Answer (score 1):

I once had something similar. Turns out the TCP was disconnecting and then re-connecting, because the MTU on the session was bad. When long output would be sent to the terminal, this is what would happen (long output means large packets means over the *real* MTU limit, say if you're connecting thru a tunnel).

In my case a modem reset (I was VPN'ing from home) solved it. In another similar case -- a configuration on the firewall/VPN-gateway did it.

Does this happen when there's a lot of output going to the console? If so, can you try to run tcpdump on the remote box, say to a file, and see if this is the case?

Comment: If TCP disconnects, your SSH session is over; it won't transparently reconnect. What you're describing is a classic firewall misconfiguration that breaks path MTU discovery. Normally, pressing a key (sending a packet from your side) wouldn't fix that, but who knows. Its certainly possible this is OP's problem.